# Searching IP ranges - Algorithm / datastructure?

Tags: c#, algorithm

Let's say I have an `IPRange` object defined like:

```
public class IPRange {
    public IPAddress Start { get; set; }
    public IPAddress End { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpireDate { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have an `IPRange[]` of these objects with hundreds or maybe thousands of entries with all different (sane) values for start/end of the ranges.

```
var myArray = new IPRange[...];
```

Now; if I have an `IPAddress`, what would be the quickest way to determine if it falls in any of the ranges? Assume:

- The array will exclusively contain items of the same AddressFamily (IPv4/IPv6) as the IP we're trying to match
- Ranges *may* or *may not* 'overlap'
- An `IPRangeComparer` (implementing `IComparer<IPRange>`, sorting by range-starts first then ('within' same start) by range-ends) and `IPRangeEqualityComparer` (implementing `IEqualityComparer<IPRange>`, returning true for same range-start and range-end) are available, as is an `IPAddressComparer` (implementing `IComparer<IPAddress>`, treating IP's as byte-arrays 'sorting' them by numerical value)

To make matters (a little) worse, the IPRange also has an `ExpireDate` (`DateTime`) property. An entry in the `IPRange[]` may expire at any time; so we also need to take that into account. The `IPRange[]` is 'reloaded' at a set interval (say once an hour) so expired items are 'purged' regularly from the array. But a range may, technically, have expired but still be in the array for up to the next reload. I don't think this is a big problem per-sé but it did add a little complexity when I did my first attempt at solving this.

I can simply iterate over the items giving O(n) performance but I'd like it to perform (much) better. I initially started with a binary-search implementation to quickly locate ranges in the array but once one is found, there may be more ranges left/right in the array, which then gives me O(n) from there on again (maybe even worse, depending on how we go from there).

I am wondering what algorithm or datastructure (if any) would help in this regard. You might say I'm trying to implement a whitelist (or blacklist, whatever) and need to quickly be able to tell if an IP is in that list or not. Once a matching range found, there's no need to look any further. I don't mind '(re)building' a datastructure every interval; I can do that in a background-task so that may take some time without worry.

On my to-look-at list, in no particular order, are: B-Tree, R(*)-Tree, Hilbert R-Tree, Enhanced Interval Trees and [this question I *just* found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1042366/215042) seems to have some interesting information too.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is an algorithmic solution for an algorithmic problem, I do not know how to program well in `C#` and the explanation is not about `IP`.

The main idea - create an array of "sub ranges" (Not a real term - will be explained soon), each element in the array will contain pointers to the real ranges.
If you have the ranges `(1,5), (3,7)` the "sub ranges" will be `(1,3), (3,5), (5,7)`. And each one of the new ranges will have pointers to the real ranges - `(1,3) -> (1,5)`, `(3,5) -> (1,5), (3,7)` and `(5,7) -> (3,7)`.

You can create this array in one iteration over the ranges after you sort them by starting time and have a helper array that keeps all the ranges that are still valid.

After you created this structure you can search for a number and see what "sub range" it is in. Can be done using binary search over the start points in the sub ranges (which are the end point of the following sub range).

Let's analyze some complexity. Every range can split the other ranges only twice so the size of the array is `n` but every element can hold `n` pointers as well so the size will be `O(n^2)` (maybe it can be less if you analyze this in an amortized way). So `O(n^2)` in size.
Build time of `O(n^2)` as well since the final structure will be in `O(n^2)`. But search time - the important thing, will be in `O(log n)`.